# Tampermonkey - insert random char randomly in a word

Tags: random, character, cpu-word

I have tried everything from replace or trying to insert a '.' at charAt.
Could not crack it, my replace, i would lose a letter or two, and charat only put the dot at the front or end of my word.

Say I have word='word' I am trying to get the return to be 'w.ord' or 'wo.rd' randomly placed in the supplied word. Any help or tips would be great.

Edit: I used the below answer and changed a little to fit my needs, if anyone wants it :

```
function randomInt(max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random()*max);
}
function Insert(a, b)
{
var int = randomInt(4);
if (int !== -1)
{
return a.substr(0, int) + b + a.substr(int);
}
return "";}
```

would use Insert("word", ".");  returns are randomly inserted "." in "word".  Thanks again for the help B.Aimene

Answer (score 1):

You must use this function, variable b is '.' and at is the position.

```
function Insert(a, b, at)
{
var position = a.indexOf(at); 

if (position !== -1)
{
    return a.substr(0, position) + b + a.substr(position);    
}  
return "Not found";}
```

Comment: Thank you! I edited this a little bit and got exactly what I needed! Will post update in main post incase someone else wants to see it.